# Searching for signal calls in a Mach-O multiarch binary

Tags: radare2, syscall

I'm searching for signals call in a Mach-O mutliarch using radare2. This is what I start with:

```
file sample
/tmp/sample (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/tmp/sample (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

As I'm interested by the `arm64` arch, I load the program in radare2 with:

```
r2 -a arm -b 64 -A sample
```

Then trying to find the signal calls I'm surprise by the results:

```
> asl~signal,sigaction
sigaction = 0x80.46
```

Why is radare2 talking about the `0x80` interruption although `arm64` should use `svc` instruction as stated by `man 2 syscall` ?

From there how can I find all functions calling a `SIGTRAP` ?